# Using EnumSet of a enum implementing an interface

Tags: java, enums, enumset

I have an interface

```
public interface TerminalSymbol {
    // methods ...
}
```

an enum

```
// common usage enum that I need
public enum Common implements TerminalSymbol {
    EPSILON;

    @Override
    // methods ...
}
```

and I'd like to do something like:

```
enum Term implements TerminalSymbol {
    A, B, C, ...

    @Override
    // methods ...
}

EnumSet<? extends TerminalSymbol> terminalSymbols = EnumSet.allOf(Term.class);
terminalSymbol.add(Common.EPSILON); // this line gives me error
```

and that error is (in my case):

```
The method add(capture#1-of ? extends TerminalSymbol) in the type AbstractCollection<capture#1-of ? extends TerminalSymbol> is not applicable for the arguments (Common)
```

now I know that if I use `Set<SomeInterface>` I could prevent this type of error (and I could continue with my developing of my class representing a formal grammar) but I'd like to use `EnumSet` because it's likely to be more efficient than `HashSet`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is it really critical efficiency wise that you are trying to use `EnumSet` instead of `HashSet`, or is it just for the sake of using `EnumSet`? Generics wise it looks like ultimately you are trying to create some heap pollution, because you have created a `Set` of `Term`s, but are trying to add an instance of `Common` into it.

Comment: Yeah now I realize that if I wanted to do add() I needed to add the EPSILON symbol in the enum of the terminal symbols but I needed this epsilon symbol in the common enum so I have to use the `HashSet` solution :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EnumSet` draws its efficiency from the key constraint that it contains strictly members of a single enum. It achieves this by efficiently storing its state with reliance on `ordinal` number of each enum member, basically behaving like a `BitSet`. So unfortunately you won't be able to reap its benefits if you want multiple enums.

The closest you can get to this goal is by devising your own numbering scheme which is distinct across all your enums, and using a `BitSet` to efficiently store them.

Answer (score 4):

The EnumSet can only contain members of one enum class.

From the [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html):

> All of the elements in an enum set must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the set is created.

As you note, an alternative is to use `Set<TerminalSymbol>`.

Answer (score 0):

`EnumSet` is a special implementation of `Set` interface for `enums` only. One instance of `EnumSet` can work with specific enum only because its implementation is based on `ordinal` of enum.

You created `EnumSet` for `Term` and try to add there enum member of `Common`. This is obviously impossible. You should either create `EnumSet` for `Common` or if you want to store elements of both enums there use other implementation of `Set`, e.g.  `HashSet`.